# DB results not showing on modal, displaying on modal "undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm currently developing a dashboard which is supposed to show the status of the machines and the logs of their communications. Everything is currently working, except for the communication logs not displaying in the **viewMachine** modal. It shows me in the modal just "undefined" , however, I've used also the **console.log()** option and in the Console it does show the information that should be displaying in the modal.

Here you can see how it is currently behaving:

[image: Status Dashboard]

and the code is the following:

```
function readMachineInfo(machine_id){
    var id = machine_id;
    var u = '/machineInfo/' +machine_id;
    $.ajax({
      url: u,
      type: "GET",
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
          id = data[0].id;
          name = data[0].name;
          lastComm = convertTime(data[0].lastCommunication);
          response = '<b>' +"Machine ID: " +'</b>' + id.toString();
          response2 = '<b>' +"Machine Name: " +'</b>' + name.toString();
          response3 = '<b>' +"Last Communication: " +'</b>'+lastComm.toString();
          $('#viewMachine .modal-header').html('<b><font color="gray"><h3>' +name.toString() +" info" +'</b></font></h3>');
          $('#viewMachine .modal-body').html(response  +'<p>' +response3 +'<p>' +logs(id));
              }
          });
       }

function logs(machine_id){
      var str = "";
      var URL = 'http://54.201.19.105/read/logs/' +machine_id;
          $.ajax({
             url: URL,
             type: "GET",
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function(data) {
              $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                str = str +"IP: " +item.ipAddress + " DATE/TIME: " +convertTime(item.communicationTime) +" , ";
                })
          console.log(str);
          return str;
             }
          });
}
```

The **readMachineInfo** function is the one that shows the basic information inside the Modal such as the Machine ID and the Last Communication, and it is supposed to also show up the result from the **logs** function. As you can see, in the Console it shows up the results from this function but in the Modal it shows up as "undefined".

Also, I would like to know if there's any way to add this info from the **logs** function inside the Modal but as a table.

Thanks in advance

Comment: linked answer is an excellent tutorial also

Comment: as for table you need to parse response to table html

Comment: As long as I can see you don't have any key `ipAddress` in your json but `IP' instead. The same  with the date.

Comment: Actually, I was able to solve it without using callbacks nor promises. I just removed the `return str;` from `logs(machine_id)` function and replaced it with `$('#viewMachine .modal-body p:last').html('<p>'+str);` . Also, I changed the `readMachineInfo(machine_id)` function where it says `$('#viewMachine .modal-body').html(response  +'<p>' +response3 +'<p>' +logs(id));` to just `$('#viewMachine .modal-body p:last').html('<p>'+str);` . Also, I changed the `readMachineInfo(machine_id)` function in success to: `$('#viewMachine .modal-body').html(response  +'<p>' +response3 +'<p>'); logs(id);`